# While loop iterating same answer

Tags: python

First time poster and beginner here. I'm trying to run a while loop to determine the credit card balance after one year if a person only pays the minimum monthly payment required by the credit card company each month. The problem is that the loop iterates the same answers:

```
bal = float(raw_input("Enter your outstanding balance: "))
ann = float(raw_input("Enter your annual interest rate: "))
min = float(raw_input("Enter the minimum monthly payment rate "))

month = 1
#min_monthly_paym=nt = min * bal
#interest paid = ann/12.0 * bal
#principal paid = min_monthly_payment(MMP) -interest paid(IP)
#remaining balance = bal - principal paid (PP)

mmp = min * bal
ip = ann/12.0 * bal
pp = mmp - ip
rb = bal - pp

while month <= 12:  
    print "Month:", month
    print "Minimum monthly payment:", mmp
    print "Principle paid:", pp
    print "Remaining balance:", rb
    month = month + 1
```

So it will go through all the months but will only print out the initial values of those calculations. I tried setting mmp/ip/pp/rb to each other after the print statements but the same thing happened. I'm thinking I need to create another variable but not sure what.

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Comment: Also why do you assume that values calculated outside of the while loop which are never updated again magically change in the while loop?

Comment: Your values are **never updated in the `while` and therefore for all the 12 months you still have the same mmp, ip, pp, rb**

Comment: I'm guessing maybe you're assuming that your four statements before the while loop are equations that recompute in each loop of the while loop, but they're just assignments that you'll have to place within the while loop if you want different behavior every loop

Answer (score 4):

You are doing something like:

```
a = 1
ten_times_a = a * 10

for n in range(10):
    print ten_times_a     # Output: 10, 10, 10, 10, ...
```

In the above example, `ten_times_a` is calculated **at the instant of execution**.

It does not define an equation or a rule for updating `ten_times_a` **as `a` changes.**

---

You must put the re-calculation *inside the body of the `for` loop*.

```
for a in range(10):
    ten_times_a = a * 10
    print ten_times_a     # Output: 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, ...
```

Comment: So in this scenario does a for loop make more sense given that I actually have a range (12 months)? I initially thought the same thing but maybe this could be executed with a while loop

Comment: @Pbculley `for` loop is for when you have a list of things to process, or a number to count up to. `while` is for when you don't know how many times you have to do something, so you have to keep checking if you're done yet.

Comment: I know there are different ways to approach this; I'm wondering if it can be done only by a while loop.